# WordPress: Defining shortcode inside a theme file instead of functions.php file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know how to create a shortcode inside functions.php file and use it in page, I also know how to output shortcode in a .php file.

What I am looking for is would it be possible to define a shortcode in any of the other theme's files instead of functions.php.

I am trying to convert some code to a shortcode, I've tried pasting it functions.php code but the code is very large and it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would be to link it with [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or to create it as a [custom plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [include it in  your theme files](http://alexking.org/blog/2012/07/09/include-plugin-in-wordpress-theme)

Comment: I must admit that I'm quite curious to know why adding it to your functions file did not work? Massive functions are often better being in their own required files in any case (much neater imho), but if it failed in your functions file, there may be something else wrong...

Comment: Thank you @Frits for your comments. I was thinking of require_once too but was checking if there was an alternate solution. Why did it not work? I don't know exactly, the function has 2500 lines of code and there are many other functions which need the same, I wanted to save some time finding an alternate solution.